# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have the following piece of code.  I am reading from csv and am parsing its contents to a list:

```
import csv
finput = input.reader(open(path,'rb'),delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
print finput[0]
```

the output is:

```
['"1239"', '"2249.00"', '"1"', '"3"', '"2011-02-20"']
```

Now I want to just extract the 1239 number... the first element so print finput[0][0] gives `"1239"`.  Now if I convert this to an integer:

```
el = int(finput[0][0])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1239"'
```

Why does it have those double quotes?

What is a clean way to extract the integer `1239`?

Answer (score 7):

In brief:

```
int(finput[0][0].strip('"'))
```

But why have you set `quotechar` to `|`?  Are you sure it shouldn't be `"` instead?  With it set to `"`, you should get strings without the quotes.

Comment: Indeed, remove the `delimiter` and `quotechar` and `csv` will take care of unquoting itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip).

```
el = int(finput[0][0].strip('"'))

>>> a = '"1234"'
>>> a
'"1234"'
>>> a.strip('"')
'1234'
>>> int(a.strip('"'))
1234
```

The documentation for `strip()` is as follows:

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on.

Comment: Thanks.. for the prompt reply